# Is there an elegant way to check many conditions and call corresponding functions?

Tags: java

So, say I've got lots of values and flags passed into my program from the command line, all stored as variables in some configuration object, `config`. These variables default to `null` if they are not provided by the user.

I've then got some other object, say an instance of `Dog`, which has lots of methods. Depending on the value of a specific command line argument, I may or may not want to call a specific method, possibly passing the argument value to the method.

At the moment I'm doing that like this:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();

if (config.argumentA != null) {
    dog.methodA(config.argumentA);
}
if (config.argumentB != null) {
    dog.methodB(config.argumentB);
}
if (config.boolArgument) {
    dog.methodC();
}

// ... ... ...

if (config.argumentZ != null) {
    dog.methodZ(config.argumentZ);
}
```

Now I've tried to look for a more elegant way of doing this, since this feels very dirty, but Google and Java jargon have me stumped.

I'm imagining making a map from the arguments' names to the function names, then looping through, checking each argument's value and calling the corresponding method. Does such a mapping exist in Java? Is there any way to do this nicely, or am I going about the problem completely wrong?

---

P.S.: I'm a bit of a beginner with both Java and problems like this, so pls be gentle :)

Comment: Or you could check null inside the method.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the methods don't necessarily take the cmd line arguments as arguments.

Comment: If all your methods had the same signature this would be easy with a `Map<String,Function<T,U>>` or `Map<String,Consumer<T>>` for specific `T` and `U`.  If they didn't then you're probably looking at a big `switch` statement.  If you had lots of methods but only a few different signatures a combination of `switch` (for the signatures) and `Map<...>` might simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this question relates to the programming practices. So like ***Alan Kay*** said OOP is basically message passing. Thus your code should not be making these decisions but rather passing this info to some other method of some other class, till the time it's actually needed. Now if you couple this concept with different Design patterns you'll get an elegant piece of code.

Also it's difficult to suggest a particular solution to a problem as abstract as your's.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140602/what-is-message-passing-in-oo#:~:text=Message%20passing%20simply%20means%20that,can%20itself%20be%20additional%20information.